# While if elif loop only responds after i input 3 times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner at python, currently studying Al Sweigarts "Automate the boring stuff with python" and im making a simple program that responds to you and asks questions, adding to it with each new thing that i learn. I'm trying to have it respond to a yes or no question, and respond accordingly if anything else is said with "please answer with yes or no". however it only responds after i type the answer in multiple times and i don't understand why. Here is the part of the code i'm at now.

```
print ('I am a computer, so i can calculate much faster, watch this')
print ('the multiplication table of 9 is')
for i in range (9,99,9):
     print (str(i))
print ('I could keep going forever, want me to?')
while input () != 'yes' and input () != 'no':
     print ('Please answer with yes or no')
if input () == 'no':
     print ('okay i will not')
elif input () == 'yes':
     print ('okay i will')
     for i in range (9,3009,9):
          print (str(i))
     print ('okay, that is enough')
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? I've only started studying python a few days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `input()` the interpreter will wait for a new input. You need to assign the first call to `input()` to a variable and then check its value.

```
print ('I am a computer, so i can calculate much faster, watch this')
print ('the multiplication table of 9 is')
for i in range (9,99,9):
     print (str(i))
print ('I could keep going forever, want me to?')
answer = input()
while answer != 'yes' and answer != 'no':
     print ('Please answer with yes or no')
if answer == 'no':
     print ('okay i will not')
elif answer == 'yes':
     print ('okay i will')
     for i in range (9,3009,9):
          print (str(i))
     print ('okay, that is enough')
```

**However**, this introduces an infinite loop if the user inputs anything other than `yes` or `no`.

To remedy this, see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You need to include another `answer = input()` inside the loop to prevent the infinite loop by asking until the answer is yes or no. Also you can check in a more pythonic way doing `while answer not in ['yes', 'no']:`